# Magento: Update several pages with a different tracking code

Tags: magento

I have to put some Tracking code on several pages: some category pages, homepage, cart and success page. Whats the best way to accomplish that?

I thought:

- homepage --> place the code in CMS -> pages -> home
- success --> edit the success.phtml
- cart --> edit the cart.phtml
- categories -> create a CMS block --> place layout update in the concerning category page to load CMS block

But it looks like it is just a mess because for every code I have another solution. What would you suggest to get it done? Did I miss a better solution?

Thank you,
Hannes

Answer (score 0):

If it's the same tracking code for each one, you could

- Create a .phtml file containing the code
- Add the file to the relevant hard pages (success, cart) using your layout xml files
- Add the file to the relevant soft pages (home, categories) using the custom design tab / custom layout update area.

If the code changes based on the page, then you may need to create a new module with a block that alters the tracking code according to a parameter you include in the layout.

Answer (score -1):

You can include a tracking script using the available Magento configurations fields.

1. Go to **System > Configuration > Design**
2. Under the **HTML Head** section, insert your tracking script into the **Miscellaneous Scripts** field.
3. **Save Config**, and clear your **Magento caches**.

Alternatively if you want it in the Footer instead, look under the **Footer** section and use the **Miscellaneous HTML** box there.